# How to show geolocated tweets on a map

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I have been playing around with the twitter API getting random tweets or even geo tagged tweets and also with the google maps API. However I want to combine this two and try and show geo tagged tweets on a google map. Here is my code for getting the geo tagged Tweets which work fine.

```
var geo = (geo.coordinates[0], geo.coordinates[1]) 
//var geo = (34.052234, -118.243685) 
client.get('search/tweets', { q:string.teamname, geocode: geo, count: 5},
    function searchTweets(err, data, response) {
        for(var index in data.statuses){
            var tweet = data.statuses[index]; 
            console.log(tweet.text);
            console.log(tweet.geo.coordinates) 
        }
   });
```

On a different file, I generated a map based on Longitude and Latitude, and I had the understanding that once I had retrieved the coordinates for the tweets, I could represent the tweets on a Google Map in the same way. However, my code is not working. My question is, how would I combine both pieces of code to generate a map which is marked with geo located Tweets?

```
function initialize() {

  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(geo.coordinates[0], geo.coordinates[1]);
  var mapOptions = {
  center: myLatlng
  zoom: 10,
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),      mapOptions);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: myLatlng,
  map: map,
  title:"Tweet});

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  content: 'Geo tagged Tweet',
  maxWidth:200 });

 infowindow.open(map,marker);
 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
 infowindow.open(map, marker); });
 }

 google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this (untested - I'm just writing down some thoughts).

1) You should strip down `init` so that it just contains the map set up. Ensure `map` is declared outside of the function, and include a call to the function that fetches your data using the lat/lng data.

```
var map;

function initialize() {
  var lat = geo.coordinates[0];
  var lng = geo.coordinates[1]
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
  var mapOptions = { center: myLatlng, zoom: 10 }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),      mapOptions);
  getData(lat, lng, processData);
}
```

2) You wrap your data fetching code in a new function declaration, which accepts lat/lng data, and a callback.

```
function getData(lat, lng, callback) {
  client.get('search/tweets', { q:string.teamname, geocode: geo, count: 5},
    function searchTweets(err, data, response) {
      callback(data.statuses);
    }
  )
};
```

3) Process the tweet information. For each tweet create a marker (add the marker to an array of markers) and update the map

```
function processData(data) {

  var markers = [];

  for (var i = 0, l = data.length; i < l; i++) {

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        id: i,
        position: myLatlng(data[i].geo.coordinates[0], data[i].geo.coordinates[1),
        map: map,
        title: "Tweet"
    });

    markers.push(marker);

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: data[i].text,
        maxWidth: 200
    });

    infowindow.open(map, marker);

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
       infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });

  }
}
```